# C++ Static and Dynamic Array Initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Let's have a following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct TStruct{
  int x;
  int y;
  int * ptr;

  TStruct( void ) : x( 0 ), y( 0 ), ptr( nullptr ) { }
};

int main(){
  TStruct arr[100];
  TStruct * arr2 = new TStruct[200];

  // some code working with these arrays

  for( int i = 0; i < 100; i ++ )
    if( arr[i] . ptr != nullptr )  
      delete [] arr[i] . ptr;
  for( int i = 0; i < 200; i ++ )
    if( arr2[i] . ptr != nullptr )  
      delete [] arr2[i] . ptr;      
  delete [] arr2;
  return 0;
}
```

How does `initialization` of both of these `arrays` - `static` and `dynamic` - works? Are they automatically initialized by `TStruct constructor` or do I have to initialize them manually by looping both of them and setting values for each TStruct member?

Comment: On an unrelated node, it's okay to do `delete` on a null pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so if I everytime set pointer to null value, I can just use `delete` without any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TStruct` constructor will be called 300 times with the code you're showing. A hundred times for each element in the array `arr`, and two hundred times when you allocate memory for `arr2`.

For the array `arr` the compiler generates code to call the constructor, and when you use `new[]` the operator will make sure the constructor is called.

Comment: So, for make it work, I need to have a constructor with zero parameters( void ) as it is in my code and everything will be fine?

Comment: By the way, can you answer me this question, please: Do I need to set a `pointer` to `NULL` before `allocating` with `new[]`?

Comment: @lolofon Unless you plan to check to see if it's a null pointer, you don't need to initialize a pointer to null (`NULL`, `0` or `nullptr`). And if you're initializing at the time of definition (like you do here with `arr2`) then you can't "pre-initialize" the pointer. :)

Answer (score 2):

The default constructor is being called for every instance of TStruct.
In your code snippet, there are 300 instances and 300 default constructor calls.

There's no difference between an instance created by `new`, `new[]` or the "normal" creation on the stack, when it comes to constructor calls.

In your example you created a default constructor, which is called for each instance.

If there wouldn't exist such a **self-defined default constructor**, the system would create an **auto-generated default constructor**. The generated one would call the default constructors of each data element.

In case one defines classes with dynamic parts, like in the question (using `new` to reserve memory and assign the memory adress to the pointer), you need to care about the pointer value: Setting the pointers value to `NULL` / `nullptr` at the time of instantiation is very important.

The reason is, that you (or somebody using the class) could suddenly apply `delete` to the pointers value of his instance. The default value for a pointer is *not* null, but a random adress in the memory. Deleting the object at this default random adress can lead to unexpected behaviour or crash of the program.

Answer (score 1):

> How does `initialization` of both of these `arrays` - `static` and `dynamic` - works? Are they automatically initialized by `TStruct constructor` or do I have to initialize them manually by looping both of them and setting values for each TStruct member?

Both statements will call the `TStruct` default constructor for each element instantiated, you don't need to do anything *manually*.

Comment: By "default constructor" you mean constructor implicitly created by program( uninitialized values ) or the constructor that I have created?

Comment: @lolofon If you provide a default constructor (i.e. one taking no parameters or having default values for all of them), your definition will be called.